# What is the difference between a Google Cloud flexible runtime and a custom runtime?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm hosting a Python server in the Google Cloud platform. However, I find it hard to determine what exactly is the difference between a flexible runtime and a custom runtime.

This is described in more detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes).

According to the documentation for both runtimes Dockerfile modifications are permitted.

I was using a flexible runtime. However, I needed to install some custom libraries. So I added the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes \
  libgeos-dev \
  libmagic1
RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.4

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
ADD . /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python main.py
```

Also I set this in `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: custom
vm: true
```

Does this mean it's a custom runtime now, because there's a Dockerfile and the runtime has been set to `custom`?

Or is it a flexible runtime, because it builds on one of the [predefined base images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#base_images)?

If I have to specify a Dockerfile anyway, is there any upside to using such a predefined image instead? I don't see any reason not to use another base image allowing to use Python 3.5 for example.